# Django REST framework serialize last log

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I use Django rest framework in a website, and it works well.

But I just meet a speical problem, just like this:

**`models.py`**:

```
class User(models.Model):
    uid = models.IntegerField(
        primary_key=True,
    )
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=15,
    )

class LoginLog(models.Model):
    sn = models.AutoField(
        primary_key=True,
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        to=User,
    )
    time = models.IntegerField(
        null=False,
    )
    IP = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        verbose_name='Login IP',
    )
```

**`serializers.py`**:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

class UserListView(generics.ListAPIView, ):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

How can I serialize the last `LoginLog` in `UserSerializer`?

Just return json data like this:

```
{
    "name": "admin",
    "uid": 1,
    "last_login": {
        "time": 1503414665,
        "IP": "127.0.0.1"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution can be to use [`SerializerMethodField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield):

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    login_log = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_login_log(self, obj):
        last_login_log = obj.__class__.objects.filter(user=obj.user).last()
        login_log_serializer = LoginLogSerializer(last_login_log)

        return login_log_serializer.data
```

- `obj.__class__` will simply reproduce `LoginLog`
- Then you filter those entries, which are related to your user
- You get the `last()` one and return it serialized.

It's controversial whether this is straightforward and simple, but it will give the wanted result. It's a bit hacky.

*You can have a look at this:* [Return only last entry of related model in serializer - Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33452330/return-only-last-entry-of-related-model-in-serializer-django)

Comment: I just tried, it return error as this:

`LoginLog is not JSON serializable`

Comment: @YYLeo I realized my mistake. I updated my answer with a possibly working solution.

Comment: @YYLeo Also, you need to implement a `LoginLogSerializer` since this is a nested relation.

Comment: Thank you!

I tried it yesterday, it raise another error:
`'HyperlinkedIdentityField' requires the request in the serializer context.`

I tried to overload the `UserListView.get()` method to passin the request, it raised:

`'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'pk'`

Comment: I solve the problem, just get `request` in the `get_login_log` method and passin `LoginLogSerializer`,  it works well. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Since you only want the time, and not the entire entity:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    last_login_time = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_last_login_time(self, obj):
        last_login = obj.loginlog_set.last()
        if last_login is not None:
            return last_login.time
        return None

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('uid', 'account', 'last_login_time')
```

Also, white-listing all fields on the model by default can get you into trouble and is not recommended. Be explicit (like above).